# Vue/AgGrid: Floating Filter Component, Array of Objects Cell Data

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

In my AgGrid data, I have a column which has a value of array of objects like this:

```
...
media:
[
  { title: 'Facebook', site: 'http://www.facebook.com'},
  { title: 'Twitter', site: 'http://www.twitter.com'}
  { title: 'Instagram', site: 'http://www.instagram.com'}
]
...
```

I managed to show in by cellRenderer like this

> 'Facebook, Twitter, Instagram'

But my problem is my floating filter , I don't know how to filter all columns which has for example has 'Facebook' media.

Here's my custom floating filter component:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <input type="text" @change="valueChanged($event)"/>
    `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      currentValue: ''
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {},
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    valueChanged(event) {
      this.currentValue = event.target.value
      this.params.onFloatingFilterChanged({
        model: this.buildModel()
      })
    },

    onParentModelChanged(parentModel) {
      this.currentValue = !parentModel ? 0 : parentModel.filter
    },

    buildModel() {
      if (this.currentValue === 0) {
        return null
      }
      return {
        filterType: 'text',
        type: 'equalsTo',
        filter: this.currentValue,
        filterTo: null
      }
    }
  }
});
```